# How can I download the API documentation for Sencha Touch 2.4.0?

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I download the API documentation of [Sencha Touch 2.4.0](http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-touch-2-4/)?

When I download and extract, the API documentation is a link to their website. How can I get a local copy of this?

Answer (score 3):

Offline documents are available from the online documents under the "Touch Guides" drop down menu.  You'll see a link next to each version to access the download.  http://cdn.sencha.com/downloads/docs/touch-docs-2.4.0.zip will get you the 2.4.0 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Now they've moved the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/